# Jackson Ignores Parent Class properties sent via JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am creating REST Service with spring boot and defined some classes with inheritence, however I'm not able to receive a JSON payload which I am sending from postman to the controller.

**JSON Payload which I'm sending** :

```
{
    "dummy" : "okok",
    "fullName": "okok",
    "mobileNumber": 1234567890

}
```

*I am only getting dummy property in the controller, rest of the properties not getting mapped to POJO*.
Logging statement prints following line on the console

```
ownerAccount OwnerAccount(dummy=okok)
```

*I think only OwnerAccount constructor is getting invoked and Account properties not getting initialized.*
Please help me understand the missing part or mistake I am doing here.
I have defined following structure :

**Account.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Account {
    @NotBlank(message = "fullName is mandatory")
    private String fullName;
    @NotNull(message = "mobileNumber is mandatory")
    private Long mobileNumber;
    @Valid
    private AddressRequest addressRequest;
}
```

**OwnerAccount.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class OwnerAccount extends Account {
    @NotBlank(message = "dummy is mandatory")
    private String dummy;

}
```

**OwnerController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/account/owner")
public class OwnerAccountResource {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private OwnerAccountService ownerAccountService;

    @Autowired
    public OwnerAccountResource(OwnerAccountService ownerAccountService) {
        this.ownerAccountService = ownerAccountService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity createOwnerAccount(@RequestBody @Valid OwnerAccount ownerAccountRequest) {
        logger.info("ownerAccountDto {}", ownerAccountRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ownerAccountService.createAccount(ownerAccountRequest));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you think you are not able to receive dummy field because here you are printing only Account fields because @Data add @ToString annotation but it's not printing super class fields
`logger.info("ownerAccountDto {}", ownerAccountRequest);`
but if you could debug that controller you would see dummy field is there. You need to override toString() to log dummy field or just add lombok annotation

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class OwnerAccount extends Account {
    @NotBlank(message = "dummy is mandatory")
    private String dummy;

}
```

@ToString(callSuper = true) will include fields from super class

Comment: Thanks! I got this working by adding the mentioned annotation.I forgot to provide the toString implementation which includes parent class fields.